# How to get total array count between keys to keys from multidimensional group

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have following multidimensional group array and want to get total array count from `2` key to `3` key.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [MessageIdx] => 4
                    [ID] => jack@example.com
                    [FirstName] => Jack
                    [LastName] => Jack
                    [Nickname] => Jack
                    [PhotoFilePathName] => 1452504870.png
                    [Text] =>
                    [PostedAt] => 2016-01-01 05:12:17
                    [NumLikes] => 49
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [MessageIdx] => 5
                    [ID] => tom@example.com
                    [FirstName] => Tom
                    [LastName] => 
                    [Nickname] => Tom
                    [PhotoFilePathName] => 
                    [Text] =>
                    [PostedAt] => 2016-01-01 05:25:29
                    [NumLikes] => 14
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [MessageIdx] => 6
                    [ID] => tom@example.com
                    [FirstName] => Tom
                    [LastName] => 
                    [Nickname] => Tom
                    [PhotoFilePathName] => 
                    [Text] => 
                    [PostedAt] => 2016-01-02 05:38:37
                    [NumLikes] => 5
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [MessageIdx] => 7
                    [ID] => jack@example.com
                    [FirstName] => Jack
                    [LastName] => Jack
                    [Nickname] => Jack
                    [PhotoFilePathName] => 1452504870.png
                    [Text] => 
                    [PostedAt] => 2016-01-02 08:38:37
                    [NumLikes] => 64
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [MessageIdx] => 8
                    [ID] => tom@example.com
                    [FirstName] => Tom
                    [LastName] => 
                    [Nickname] => Tom
                    [PhotoFilePathName] => 
                    [Text] => 
                    [PostedAt] => 2016-01-03 10:38:37
                    [NumLikes] => 54
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [MessageIdx] => 9
                    [ID] => jack@example.com
                    [FirstName] => Jack
                    [LastName] => Jack
                    [Nickname] => Jack
                    [PhotoFilePathName] => 1452504870.png
                    [Text] => 
                    [PostedAt] => 2016-01-03 12:49:47
                    [NumLikes] => 19
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [MessageIdx] => 10
                    [ID] => tom@example.com
                    [FirstName] => Tom
                    [LastName] => 
                    [Nickname] => Tom
                    [PhotoFilePathName] => 
                    [Text] => 
                    [PostedAt] => 2016-01-04 06:23:26
                    [NumLikes] => 5
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [MessageIdx] => 11
                    [ID] => tom@example.com
                    [FirstName] => Tom
                    [LastName] => 
                    [Nickname] => Tom
                    [PhotoFilePathName] => 
                    [Text] =>
                    [PostedAt] => 2016-01-04 10:36:34
                    [NumLikes] => 38
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [MessageIdx] => 12
                    [ID] => tom@example.com
                    [FirstName] => Tom
                    [LastName] => 
                    [Nickname] => Tom
                    [PhotoFilePathName] => 
                    [Text] =>
                    [PostedAt] => 2016-01-05 10:36:34
                    [NumLikes] => 98
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [MessageIdx] => 13
                    [ID] => jack@example.com
                    [FirstName] => Jack
                    [LastName] => Jack
                    [Nickname] => Jack
                    [PhotoFilePathName] => 1452504870.png
                    [Text] =>
                    [PostedAt] => 2016-01-05 14:18:41
                    [NumLikes] => 87
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [MessageIdx] => 14
                    [ID] => jack@example.com
                    [FirstName] => Jack
                    [LastName] => Jack
                    [Nickname] => Jack
                    [PhotoFilePathName] => 1452504870.png
                    [Text] => 
                    [PostedAt] => 2016-01-06 09:29:17
                    [NumLikes] => 59
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [MessageIdx] => 15
                    [ID] => tom@example.com
                    [FirstName] => Tom
                    [LastName] => 
                    [Nickname] => Tom
                    [PhotoFilePathName] => 
                    [Text] =>
                    [PostedAt] => 2016-01-06 09:29:17
                    [NumLikes] => 72
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [MessageIdx] => 16
                    [ID] => jack@example.com
                    [FirstName] => Jack
                    [LastName] => Jack
                    [Nickname] => Jack
                    [PhotoFilePathName] => 1452504870.png
                    [Text] =>
                    [PostedAt] => 2016-01-06 12:39:33
                    [NumLikes] => 69
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [MessageIdx] => 17
                    [ID] => tom@example.com
                    [FirstName] => Tom
                    [LastName] => 
                    [Nickname] => Tom
                    [PhotoFilePathName] => 
                    [Text] =>
                    [PostedAt] => 2016-01-07 06:10:51
                    [NumLikes] => 74
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [MessageIdx] => 18
                    [ID] => jack@example.com
                    [FirstName] => Jack
                    [LastName] => Jack
                    [Nickname] => Jack
                    [PhotoFilePathName] => 1452504870.png
                    [Text] => 
                    [PostedAt] => 2016-01-07 12:28:51
                    [NumLikes] => 19
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [MessageIdx] => 19
                    [ID] => jack@example.com
                    [FirstName] => Jack
                    [LastName] => Jack
                    [Nickname] => Jack
                    [PhotoFilePathName] => 1452504870.png
                    [Text] =>
                    [PostedAt] => 2016-01-08 02:06:10
                    [NumLikes] => 32
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [MessageIdx] => 20
                    [ID] => tom@example.com
                    [FirstName] => Tom
                    [LastName] => 
                    [Nickname] => Tom
                    [PhotoFilePathName] => 
                    [Text] =>
                    [PostedAt] => 2016-01-08 07:15:10
                    [NumLikes] => 47
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [MessageIdx] => 21
                    [ID] => tom@example.com
                    [FirstName] => Tom
                    [LastName] => 
                    [Nickname] => Tom
                    [PhotoFilePathName] => 
                    [Text] =>
                    [PostedAt] => 2016-01-09 11:24:27
                    [NumLikes] => 82
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [MessageIdx] => 22
                    [ID] => tom@example.com
                    [FirstName] => Tom
                    [LastName] => 
                    [Nickname] => Tom
                    [PhotoFilePathName] => 
                    [Text] =>
                    [PostedAt] => 2016-01-09 14:23:08
                    [NumLikes] => 71
                )

        )

)
```

Now I want to start array total between `2` key to the last key `3`.

```
Array
    (
        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [MessageIdx] => 14
                        [ID] => jack@example.com
                        [FirstName] => Jack
                        [LastName] => Jack
                        [Nickname] => Jack
                        [PhotoFilePathName] => 1452504870.png
                        [Text] =>
                        [PostedAt] => 2016-01-06 09:29:17
                        [NumLikes] => 59
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [MessageIdx] => 15
                        [ID] => tom@example.com
                        [FirstName] => Tom
                        [LastName] => 
                        [Nickname] => Tom
                        [PhotoFilePathName] => 
                        [Text] =>
                        [PostedAt] => 2016-01-06 09:29:17
                        [NumLikes] => 72
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [MessageIdx] => 16
                        [ID] => jack@example.com
                        [FirstName] => Jack
                        [LastName] => Jack
                        [Nickname] => Jack
                        [PhotoFilePathName] => 1452504870.png
                        [Text] =>
                        [PostedAt] => 2016-01-06 12:39:33
                        [NumLikes] => 69
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [MessageIdx] => 17
                        [ID] => tom@example.com
                        [FirstName] => Tom
                        [LastName] => 
                        [Nickname] => Tom
                        [PhotoFilePathName] => 
                        [Text] =>
                        [PostedAt] => 2016-01-07 06:10:51
                        [NumLikes] => 74
                    )

                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [MessageIdx] => 18
                        [ID] => jack@example.com
                        [FirstName] => Jack
                        [LastName] => Jack
                        [Nickname] => Jack
                        [PhotoFilePathName] => 1452504870.png
                        [Text] =>
                        [PostedAt] => 2016-01-07 12:28:51
                        [NumLikes] => 19
                    )

            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [MessageIdx] => 19
                        [ID] => jack@example.com
                        [FirstName] => Jack
                        [LastName] => Jack
                        [Nickname] => Jack
                        [PhotoFilePathName] => 1452504870.png
                        [Text] =>
                        [PostedAt] => 2016-01-08 02:06:10
                        [NumLikes] => 32
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [MessageIdx] => 20
                        [ID] => tom@example.com
                        [FirstName] => Tom
                        [LastName] => 
                        [Nickname] => Tom
                        [PhotoFilePathName] => 
                        [Text] =>
                        [PostedAt] => 2016-01-08 07:15:10
                        [NumLikes] => 47
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [MessageIdx] => 21
                        [ID] => tom@example.com
                        [FirstName] => Tom
                        [LastName] => 
                        [Nickname] => Tom
                        [PhotoFilePathName] => 
                        [Text] =>
                        [PostedAt] => 2016-01-09 11:24:27
                        [NumLikes] => 82
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [MessageIdx] => 22
                        [ID] => tom@example.com
                        [FirstName] => Tom
                        [LastName] => 
                        [Nickname] => Tom
                        [PhotoFilePathName] => 
                        [Text] =>
                        [PostedAt] => 2016-01-09 14:23:08
                        [NumLikes] => 71
                    )

            )

    )
```

There are `9` array available from `2` key to `3` and I want get `9` count from array.

Any idea how to get total count of array?

Thanks.

Comment: array_slice() combined with array_walk()  and count() perhaps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

```
$selected_keys= range(2, 3);
$count= 0;
foreach($selected_keys as $selected_key) {
   $count+= count($arr[$selected_key]);
}
echo $count;
```

Output

```
9
```

Answer (score 0):

For your specific question, you could just count those two indexs and sum them:

```
$total = count($array[2]) + count(array[3]);
```

if you wanted a more dynamic solution, that works between key x and y:

```
function countRange($array, $start, $end){
    $total = 0;
    foreach(range($start, $end) as $index){
        if(isset($array[$index]) && is_array($array[$index])){
            $total += count($array[$index]);
        }
    }
    return $total;
}

echo 'total: ' . countRange($array, 2, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the keys correctly then you can try this -

```
$keys= range(2, 3);
$count= 0;

foreach($keys as $key) {
   $count+= count($yourarray[$key]);
}
```

You can also add checks if you are not sure about the keys -

```
$num = !empty($yourarray[$key]) ? count($yourarray[$key]) : 0;
$count+= $num;
```